# Trying to make sense of bash redirection syntaxes and their outputs

Tags: bash, io-redirection, stdout, stderr

I'm new to Linux and trying to understand how redirections work.

I have been testing various syntaxes for redirecting `stdout` and `stderr` to the same file, which don't all produce the same results.

For example, if I try to list 2 files that don't exist (`file1` and `file2`) and 2 that do (`foo` and `fz`):

**Syntax #1** (without redirection):

```
$ ls file1 foo fz file2
```

Here's the output I get in terminal:

```
ls: cannot access file1: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access file2: No such file or directory
foo  fz
```

**Syntax #2:**

Now, with redirection:

```
$ ls file1 foo fz file2 > redirect 2>&1
```

The `redirect` file contains the same as the result for Syntax #1:

```
ls: cannot access file1: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access file2: No such file or directory
foo
fz
```

So with both of the above syntaxes, it seems that the shell prints `stderr` first, then `stdout`.

**Syntax #3:**

Now, if I try with either of the following syntaxes:

```
$ ls file1 foo fz file2 > redirect 2> redirect
```

or

```
$ ls file1 foo fz file2 2> redirect > redirect
```

Then the `redirect` file will contain this:

```
foo
fz
nnot access file1: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access file2: No such file or directory
```

Here it looks like `stdout` is printed before `stderr`, but then we see that the beginning of `stderr` is "cropped" by the same number of characters as `stdout`.

The `stdout` is 6 chars long (`foo fz`, carriage return included), so the first 6 chars of the `stderr` (`ls: ca`) have been overwritten by `stdout`.
So it actually seems like `stderr` was printed first, and that `stdout` was then printed over `stderr` instead of being appended to it.

However, it would have made more sense to me if `stderr` had been *completely* erased and replaced with `stdout`, rather than just partially overwitten.

**Syntax #4:**

The only way I have found to correct Syntax #3 is by adding the append operator to the `stdout`:

```
$ ls file1 foo fz file2 >> redirect 2> redirect
```

or

```
$ ls file1 foo fz file2 2> redirect >> redirect
```

Which produces the same as Syntax #2:

```
ls: cannot access file1: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access file2: No such file or directory
foo
fz
```

[This article here](http://teaching.idallen.com/cst8207/13w/notes/200_redirection.html#redirecting-both-stdout-and-stderr-using-21) explains that Syntax #3 is wrong (presumably, so is Syntax #4). But for argument's sake: why is Syntax #3 wrong? What exactly is it telling (or *not* telling) the shell to do as opposed to Syntax #2?

Also, is there a reason why the output always displays `stderr` before `stdout`?

Thank you!

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but the simplest way to redirect *both* `stdout` and `stderr` to the same file is `&>`, as in `ls file1 foo fz file2 &> redirect`.

Comment: @gardenhead Thanks, yes, I have come across this, but as I'm only a novice I'm really trying to break things down to make sure I understand everything correctly. Also I've read that while `&>` is a simpler and more modern way to redirect both, it won't work on older shells, and that it is safer to get in the habit of using `> redirect 2>&1` for now.

Answer (score 6):

It's just like running two processes to write to the same file at the same time...bad idea.  You wind up with two different open file handles and your data can get garbled (as it does in #3 above).  Using syntax #2 is correct; it makes **one** file handle and points both stderr and stdout to the same place.

As for stderr always being printed first, there is no rule on this whatsoever.  I suspect with `ls` it is because `ls` needs to check every entry in the directory before it can actually state that a particular file doesn't exist.  So rather than make N passes over the directory table, it makes a single pass, checking for all command line arguments given, reports the errors, and prints the files it found.  Other commands may print to stderr after stdout, or even alternate between them.

Comment: Right, thank you. I had a feeling the print order of stderr and stdout might be inherent to the command itself. So Syntax #3 is bound to make a mess then. Despite producing what looks like a clean output, Syntax #4 also uses two separate processes targetting the same file, so I assume it should be avoided as well.

Comment: @LePoufCelebre, correct.  Syntax #2 is the only correct way to point stderr and stdout to the same place.  (Well, `ls 2> redirect >&2` is fine also.)

Answer (score 6):

Adding to wildcard's answer, `stdout` is usually buffered (stored in memory to be written out later), while `stderr` never is (you want error messages to show up, even if the program crashes before writing anything out). So `stderr` will usually show up earlier.

Comment: That's good to know. It does sound more sensible to print errors as soon as they occur. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Not a developer here or a kernel expert. So I can not comment on any code but in syntax #3 you are piping `stdout` and `stderr` into the same file using two different pipes.  So the common file you are sending both outputs to, is possibly having resource contention issues from 2 different pipes. Considering non-real time nature of the OS, two pipes are feeding information into the same file, probably at the same time. Which might explain missing characters.

In syntax #2, you redirecting the `stderr` into the same pipe for `stdout` At that point, the file has one pipe coming in and shell manages this pipe against race conditions.

This is my educated guess and a guess only. Nothing to substantiate it.

Comment: Your guess is most welcome. It gives a more visual idea of what's going on with both syntaxes. Thank you.