# can we save mysql error to a file?

Tags: shell-script, mysql

I would like to know is there any way to log the mysql query error which prints on screen.

Example:

```
mysql -u$UserName -p$Password -D $DBName -e "ALTER TABLE  collect ADD  path VARCHAR( 250 ) NOT NULL AFTER  my_path "
```

This will return duplicate column if it exists... I would like to log this error on a text file, which will help in my automation.

Comment: *I would like to log **this** error* OR all possible errors?

Comment: See also [Trying to make sense of bash redirection syntaxes and their outputs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/269057/80216).

Comment: See also [suppress error messages in a bash script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/184804/80216).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Redirect the standard error stream of `mysql` to a file:

```
mysql ...options... 2>error_log.txt
```

Furthermore, make sure that you double quote the variable `$UserName` (and the others) so that spaces and characters that may be special to the shell are preserved.

See the answers to the following question about how to avoid using a password on the command line for MySQL: [Use a password in shell-script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/396277/use-a-password-in-shell-script)